# Does JavaFX support regular expressions (or wild cards) in CSS?

Tags: java, css, regex, javafx, javafx-css

I've tried using wild cards in CSS selectors for JavaFX UI (TableView), but that doesn't seem to work, although [JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) notes that it's based on CSS version 2.1:

> JavaFX Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is based on the W3C CSS version
>   2.1 with some additions from current work on version 3.

For example:

```css
TableColumnHeader[id|="column"] > .label
{
    -fx-graphic: url("ico.png");
}
```

The above CSS is an attempt to show an icon "ico.png" on all column headers of a TableView

- `TableColumnHeader` is the type selector for the table's column header `Node`
- `.label` is the style class for the Label node rendered within the column header
- `[id|="column"]` is similar to the example mentioned here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#matching-attrs
- The `id` of column header is inherited from its `TableColumn`. The `id` is set on the `TableColumn` object as follows: `tableColumn.setId("column-"+ columnName)` where `columnName` is a String variable

The above CSS doesn't work. Any variation that includes `[id=...]`, or any other attribute other than `id` doesn't work.

Is this a limitation in JavaFX? or is there a way to make it work?

Comment: “The `id` of column header is inherited from its `TableColumn`.”  Is that documented somewhere?  I’ve never heard of an `id` attribute, or any attribute except xmlns, being inherited.  In HTML and XML documents, each `id` value is required to be unique throughout the document;  I don’t know if JavaFX enforces that uniqueness, but if it didn’t, the effectiveness of `#idvalue` selectors would be compromised.

Comment: Hi @VGR ,Not sure if it's documented somewhere, but I had a look inside TableColumnHeader constructor code, and added debug code to print out the IDs of TableColumnHeaders.
At the constructor of: `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader`, there's this call `setId(column.getId());`

Comment: The only thing I found in the CSS Reference is: "While the JavaFX CSS parser will parse valid CSS syntax, it is not a fully compliant CSS parser. One should not expect the parser to handle syntax not specified in this document.". So most probaby you cannot use matching attributes.

Comment: If the copying of the `id` is not documented, any future release of JavaFX is free to remove it.  Also, it appears the JavaFX CSS engine does not recognize the `id` attribute at all (though it does honor the `#idvalue` notation).  And even if it did, the `|=` notation expects `-` as a delimiter, so `id|="column"` would match "column-Date" but not "columnDate".  For all these reasons, I think I would give up on using CSS and just use [TableColumn.setGraphic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#setGraphic-javafx.scene.Node-) in code.

Comment: Thanks @DVarga and @VGR.
I'll use `TableColumn`style class instead of `id`, as more than one column can share the same class, and the class is supported by CSS parser.
I think it's ok too that the `id` gets copied to `TableColumnHeader` as `TableColumnHeader`is a rendered representation of `TableColumn` (along with other nodes that make up the table), `TableColumn` is more like a logical definition of the column. So at the end, it's one node (header) in the table that will have the `id`